# Draw a convex hull and a plane using Pgfplots, in this specific case:

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have 2 surfaces to plot. The first one is a convex hull that passes through 7 points, and the second one is a plane formed by 3 points. The corresponding code is the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
\begin{axis}[mesh/ordering=y varies]
\addplot3[surf] coordinates {
 (1,0,0) (0,1,0) (0,0,1)
 (0.85,0.85,0) (0.85,0,0.85) (0,0.85,0.85)
 (0.75,0.75,0.75) (0.75,0.75,0.75) (0.75,0.75,0.75)
};
\addplot3[surf] coordinates {
 (2,0,0) (0,2,0) (0,0,2) 
}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I know this is a bad code but I posted it here just to show the points..  Please I need to know how can I correctly represent the 2 plots.

Comment: You can start by drawing the plane using its equation. For the other surface, what is your problem?

Comment: Ok for the plane.. but for the convex hull I am not able to plot the convex hull of this point. In other words, I don't know if pgfplots will connect all these points to each other, and I am not sure if the posted code is the correct way to do it..

Comment: the fastest way to know is to try :)

Comment: I tried many times.. I just need to know how  \addplot3[surf] coordinates {}   links the points and why, for ex, I cannot put 3 points in the first row and just one point in the second one..